# How to Track Individual Layer Usage Within Map Service?

Tags: arcgis-server, layers, statistics, map-service

I have a public-facing web mapping application (flex-based), and I need to get the usage/statistics on the layers that people are using, however, a lot of these layers are one of many within a map service (e.g. "Utilities" is a service that has many layers within it).  Besides splitting them apart into separate services, what are some ways I can go about tracking this information?  As far as I know, ArcGIS Server stats only show usage by service (not the layers within) and Google Analytics only displays information on page views/widget usage.

Comment: Have you considered a Server Object Interceptor (SOI) to log how many requests come for particular LayerIDs ?

Comment: Kirk, I have not considered an SOI before.  Thanks for your suggestion, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this FlexViewer widget](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=151491cec5be41b5bb5c81dfe63b1669) that allows for tracking from Google Analytics.  It has EventListeners to listen out for certain events the user is triggering in the interface.

From the above link:

> Logging options without extra coding include:
>       Record a log of widgets as they are opened.
>       Record a log of each basemap if it is switched on.
>       Record a log of map's interactive mode, such as Draw point, line, etc. These options can be set to true in the GoogleAnalyticsWidget.xml
>   file if you wish to log them.
>
> For developers, the widget is also set to listen for a
>   GoogleAnalyticsWidgetEvent. This will allow more detalied logging
>   options by dispatching a GoogleAnalyticsWidgetEvent anywhere within
>   the flexviewer code. For example if you wanted to log each time the
>   search button is clicked on myWidget, you would add the following to
>   the buttons click event.

Would not be too hard to add a new event listener for individual layers within a map service.

With that said - I prefer the line of thinking Kirk mentions in his comment through using a Service Object Interceptor.  Flex has been retired by Esri and the majority of browsers out there.  It would be a more futureproof path to look at an SOI os possibly an Esri partner that provides more advanced logging such as [GeoCortex Analytics](http://www.geocortex.com/products/geocortex-analytics/).